# How to find the first free key in an array

Tags: php, arrays

We all know that arrays are actually ordered trees in PHP. Given that, an array index (integer key) need not be in any strict order or even exist at all. So, given an array like:

```
array( 1 => 'A', 5 => 'B', 2 => 'C', 3 => 'D', 6 => 'E', 0 => 'F' )
```

How can we determine the lowest (non negative) integer of the first empty key, without re-indexing the array? In this case it would be `4`.

Comment: Brute force it with a loop?

Comment: So, you wish to obtain the missing key number?

Comment: `$i = 0; while(true){if(!isset($array[$i])) break;$i++}`.

Comment: @Wrikken Elegent, I like, like a lot.

Comment: @Wrikken using `break;` in while cycle is not the best solution. There is also any solution without break: `$i = 0; while(isset($array[$i])) { $i++; }`

Comment: @Mr.Smith: youi are totally correct ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy solution by `while` loop:

```
function firstFreeKey($array)
{
  $i = 0;
  while(isset($array[$i])) $i++;
  return $i;
}

$array = array( 1 => 'A', 5 => 'B', 2 => 'C', 3 => 'D', 6 => 'E', 0 => 'F' );

echo firstFreeKey($array);
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: @Waldermort As long as your arrays has a minimum key of 0. Be aware of that.

Comment: But arrays should start with 0. And if you don't want to use zero, just edit `$i = 0` to any else start number or you can make it as parameter in function. `function firstFreeKey($array, $i = 0)`

Comment: @CodeAngry: well, the OP _explicitly_ states: _"determine the lowest (non negative) integer"_. Which is what it does. If we allow negative integers, will you be asking about floats next?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array( 1 => 'A', 5 => 'B', 2 => 'C', 3 => 'D', 6 => 'E', 0 => 'F' );
for($i = 0, $l = count($a); $i < $l; $i++) if(!array_key_exists($i, $a)) break;
echo $i; // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

**First method** is getting fancy with arrays.

```
// STUPID FANCY WAY (playing with arrays)
$array = array( 1 => 'A', 5 => 'B', 2 => 'C', 3 => 'D', 6 => 'E', 0 => 'F' );
// fetch existing keys
$keys = array_keys($array);
// build a range with all keys (between min and max)
$keys_all = range(min($keys), max($keys));
// difference between all and existing
$keys_diff = array_diff($keys_all, $keys);
// fetch the first in difference (min)
$min_key = reset($keys_diff);
// output it
var_dump($min_key);
```

**Second method** is actually viable as it spares the need for extra arrays in memory.

```
// PROPER WAY (not extra array operations)
$array = array( 1 => 'A', 5 => 'B', 2 => 'C', 3 => 'D', 6 => 'E', 0 => 'F' );
// fetch existing keys
$keys = array_keys($array);
// nullify first
$min_key = null;
// loop all keys and find missing one (skip 1st and last, they totally exist!)
for($key = ($min = min($keys)) + 1, $max = max($keys); $key < $max; ++$key){
    if(!isset($array[$key])){
        $min_key = $key;
        break;
    }
}
// output it
var_dump($min_key);
```

*I'll explain if comments are not enough.*

**PS**: *This method handles situation when minimum key value is not `0`. Hence it's independent of range `min` and `max`. And keys need to be integers, obviously.*

Comment: So, this returns `NULL` rather then the next available empty key if they are gapless? I'd make it at least `$key <= ($max+1)`.

Comment: Oh, damn, BTW: `$min = min(0,min($keys));` of course.. otherwise it may fail to capture a low integer at the very start.

Comment: @Wrikken Yes. I like `NULL`. It's meaningful. I'm not sure what the expected behavior is if not gap is found.

Comment: Well, the question is for _"the first empty key"_, there is no mention of gaps and it needing to be in one anywhere. But we can ask the OP if that is what (s)he meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = array(1 => 'A', 5 => 'B', 2 => 'C', 3 => 'D', 6 => 'E', 0 => 'F');
$bar = array(1 => 'A', 4 => 'Z', 2 => 'L', 3 => 'N');

function firstFreeKey($array)
{
    ksort($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i++) {
        if (!isset($array[$i])) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return count($array) + 1;
}

function firstFreeKeyNotZero($array)
{
    $i = min(array_keys($array));
    while (isset($array[$i])) {
        $i++;
    }
    return $i;
}

echo firstFreeKey($foo); //returns 4
echo firstFreeKey($bar); //returns 0
echo firstFreeKeyNotZero($foo); //returns 4
echo firstFreeKeyNotZero($bar); //returns 5
```

Edit: Added case where not starting from 0, as requested by CodeAngry

Comment: What if the keys don't start at 0?

Comment: Added an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly one of the longest answers, but the most explained.

```
$Jumbled_Arr = array(
1 => "test",
3 => "another",
4 => "t",
7 => "kfkfk",
9 => "fk"



);
function GetMissingKey($Array,$Return_Type = false){

    // Get the Maximum Key Value
    $Max_Key = max(array_keys($Array));
        // Treat this as the default array index, as all numerical arrays start at a 0 key set
        $Counter = 0;
        // A Blank array to be maniuplated
    $Generated_Array = array();
        // Generate a full array based on the maximum value and the array index, this will create a keyset from 0 to the highest value 
    while ($Counter < $Max_Key){
            $Generated_Array[] = $Counter;
        $Counter++;
    }   

    // Discover the differences between the correctly formed array and the specified array keys 
    $Missing_Key = array_diff($Generated_Array,array_keys($Array));

            // Work with the second parameter, as the settings. 
        if ($Return_Type === true){
        // If set to true, we are expecting more than 1 free key within the array, so we will return the entire array 
            return $Missing_Key;
        }elseif ($Return_Type === false){
        // If set to false (or blank) we are expecting a single free key to be discovered & we will return it as an imploded array
            return implode($Missing_Key);
        }
}
    print_R(GetMissingKey($Jumbled_Arr,true));
```

If true is passed through to this function, you will be returned with an array of missing keys.

If false is passed through, then you will be returned with a single integer (careful when if expecting more than one key to be returned).

Comment: I don't see why most people are so performance aware, we're talking micro seconds, unless it hangs above a second to finish working, then i'll take it as a problem

Comment: Try it with a larger array. It has high constant (n) runtime and high constant (n) memory.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Alright, yeah. I see the problem with huge arrays

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
echo min(array_keys($array));
```

`array_keys` returns the list of keys for the array, and `min` determines the lowest value in the array.

Expanding following comments :

As the array is a continous int value, you can do the following

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$arr2 = range(0,max($keys));

// diff gets the missing elements
$missing = array_diff($arr2,$keys);

echo $missing[0];
```

Not sure on the performance of this vs brute force, but it can be tested.

Comment: I want a non existing key, array_keys returns existing.

Comment: @Waldermort ah, I misread your question. I have updated my answer to reflect your comment

Answer (score 0):

To get all free keys:

```
$aArray = array(1 => 'A', 5 => 'B', 2 => 'C', 3 => 'D', 6 => 'E');
$iMaxKey = 7; //max key you will need
$aAllKeys = range(0, iMaxKey); //create array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$aAllFreeKeys = array_diff_key($aAllKeys, $aArray); //will be: array(0,4,7);
```

and now if you need first free key:

```
$iKey = array_shift($aAllFreeKeys);
```