# Restart the PHP array indexes

Tags: php, sockets

I will explain:
I have a socket `socket.php` file that will add a connection for each user so the user has multiple connections from different devices.

```
$clients[] = $socketChange; // array_push($clients,$socketChange); // 505
$end = key (array_slice ($clients, -1, 1, TRUE)); // extract 505
$userConexion [$userId] [] = $end; // add to clientID socket 505
```

what you do is add each connection to the client array and then the last added socket assign it to the corresponding user. so the user can have multiple sessions of different devices and in all will receive the information in real time.

Now what is my question is ...

how can I control of positions, that is, if they connect and disconnect `1k` from users
for the user number 1001 `$ clients` he will show me`$ clients [1001]`how he could restart the counter without removing the users already connected.

i delete clients socket close with `unset()` `array_shift()` reorder bad `$clients` sockets.

example:

```
$clients[0] = resource 0;
$clients[1,433]  = empty;
$clients[434]  = resource 434;
$clients[435]  = resource 435;
$clients[436,450]  = empty;
$clients[451]  = resource 435;
$clients[452,999]  = empty;
$clients[1000] = resource 1000;
```

new connexion `1001`
add to empty positions.

**example:**

```
<?php 

$a1 = array();
$a2 = array();

for ($i=1; $i < 4 ; $i++) { 
    $a1[] = array("hello{$i}" => "hello{$i}");
    $a2[] = array("hello{$i}" => "hello{$i}");
}

echo "<pre>";
unset($a1[1]);
unset($a2[1]);

$a1[] = array("hello11" => "hello11");
array_push($a2, array("hello11" => "hello11"));

print_r($a1); // 0,2,3
print_r($a2); // 0,2,3

// need insert in position empty in this example `1`.
```

Comment: You want to find the last key?  There is a new way to do this in php (and that would make this a duplicate question). Maybe I misunderstand your requirement.

Comment: @mickmackusa if you can help me find a better way to allocate the sockets per user. I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I am trying to find a reason not to close with https://stackoverflow.com/a/52098132/2943403  I think I don't follow your question.  I suppose I find your question Unclear.  Your terminology is confusing to me.  "Limit of positions".

Comment: So you wish to find the lowest available integer key? https://stackoverflow.com/q/22076141/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/48066561/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but if you want to add the new connection's data in the first unoccupied index of your array, here is something you can do :

```
for($i=0; $i<count($clients)+1; $i++) {
  if(!isset($clients[$i]) {
    $clients[$i] = resource 1001;
    break;
  }
}
```

Use `empty($clients[$i])` instead of `!isset($clients[$i])` if the index still exist in the array and simply do not have a value anymore.

Comment: I was simply using the word he used to describe his datas.

Comment: exelent!     `[3] => Resource id #9
    [4] => Resource id #10
    [2] => Resource id #11` I optimize it by saving the index of the resources released when the user disconnects

Comment: `count()` should not be called on every iteration

Comment: @mickmackusa I didn't know for() was working that way. I learned something today, thanks.